# Parallel transport on the two-sphere

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Let $M=\mathbb{S}^2\setminus\{x_S\}$ be the sphere without the South Pole $x_S$, endowed with the classical metric $$g=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sin^2(\theta)\end{bmatrix}.$$ For any $x\in M$ let $\gamma_x$ be the unique geodesic from $x$ to the North Pole $x_N$. I have to compute explicitly the parallel transport of any vector $v\in T_xM$ from $x$ to the North Pole.

My attempt: by linearity it suffices to compute it for the basis $(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta},\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi})$. Letting $\{e_1,e_2\}$ be the canonical basis of $T_{x_N}M$ endowed by the inclusion $\mathbb{S}^2\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ we can actually claim that for any $x=(\theta,\varphi)\in M$, it holds $$P_{\gamma_x}(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\Bigl\vert_{(\theta,\varphi)})=\cos(\varphi)e_1+\sin(\varphi)e_2,\quad P_{\gamma_x}(\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi}\Bigl\vert_{(\theta,\varphi)})=\sin(\theta)\Bigl(-\sin(\varphi)e_1+\cos(\varphi)e_2\Bigr),$$
where $P_{\gamma_x}$ is the parallel transport to the North Pole along $\gamma_x$.

> Does it looks correct? I found this result only looking at the problem geometrically (imagining the vectors moving) and also knowing that the parallel transport preserves the inner product (that is why $\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi}$ is rescaled).

Comment: It is indeed not clear how you get $e_1, e_2 $ only. They are not tangent vector away from $x_N$.

Comment: @ArcticChar - But they only occur in expressions for the vectors at $x_N$, where they form a basis, so of course all such vectors are expressible in terms of them only.

Comment: However, there is an issue with the problem statement itself. If $x_S$ is the south pole, then contrary to the claim, there is not a *unique* geodesic from $x_S$ to $x_N$, and the result of parallel transport will depend on which geodesic between the two you use.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, you are right. I misread and thought the parallel transport start from $x_N$.

Comment: You are right that’s a typo, I take $M$ without the south pole, I edit it now

Comment: Parallel transport should not change the magnitude of the vector. $\partial/\partial\varphi$ is a unit vector, and its transported image should also be a unit vector.

Comment: It is not a unit vector: $g(\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi},\frac{\partial}{\partial\varphi})=\sin^2(\theta)$. That's why I have to rescale it.